# Override file doesnt work in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've file which I was **able to read** and get the data and now I want to override the file content but what I try below doesn't work am I missing something ?

```
        var str = "t123";
        fs.writeFile('C:\\test.txt',str,'utf8',{'flags': 'a+'},function(){
            fs.readFile('C:\\test.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
                console.log(data === str)
                res.send(data);
            });
        });
```

I've verify that the file is not read-only...
when I put the err I got the following but the file is closed...

```
Error: EPERM, open 'C:\test.txt'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like a permission error. Open your command prompt as an Administrator before you run your server using nodemon. (Moved from comment to the answer section at the request of OP)

Comment: Deleting your answer and reposting it because it received a downvote is not acceptable. I downvoted this, because it is bad advice. The script shouldn't be run as a super user. The permissions on the file should be set correctly instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** Permission error to this file C:\test.txt RUN as administrator this file.

I just tried below mentioned code which is working fine. test.txt and write.js are in the same directory.

```
// write.js
var fs = require('fs'); 
var str = "this is my new text";
fs.writeFile('test.txt',str,'utf8',{'flags': 'a+'},function(){
    fs.readFile('test.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        console.log(data === str)
    });
});
```

**OUTPUT:**  true